# Self-hosting a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, self-hosting

I'm using a WCF service and i'm hosting it in a console application. I have all of my configuration in an XML file. The service works well and i can connect it it fine from the client, but what bothers me is that when i start it the WcfSvcHost app starts (in my icon tray) and says "Your service(s) have been hosted....". But when i click on it it shows my service and under status it says Stopped (with the error that there are no endpoints defined).

I have two projects, one with the service and another one that hosts it. The error points to the project that has the service in it, which has no configuration defined since ( i assume ) it is not needed there. I have all of my configuration in the project that hosts the service, inside App.config.

How do i get rid of the message? And is it even a problem or is it normal?

P.S. I only start the project that hosts the service, not the one that has the service code.

Comment: I'm confused. Wouldn't IIS host your service? How does another project host a WCF service?

Comment: @crush You can host a WCF service from code by just picking a port and saying "Start listening for HTTP requests."

Comment: @TimothyShields Would a Web.config apply in that situation?

Comment: Yes you can use IIS but you can also self-host it, simply by including the service project in another project, adding an assembly reference to System.ServiceModel and doing this in the code: `ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourService));` and opening it: `selfHost.Open();`

Comment: You'd lose all the benefits of IIS then, wouldn't you? Isn't it IIS that handles things like the Web.config? Maybe I'm wrong because I've never used a WCF service in this manner yet.

Comment: @crush, no you could not use Web.config if using a standard application, you'd use App.config for the configuration. Also, in my situation, i need to self host it because IIS is not an option.

Comment: @crush: you'd also **avoid** all the shortcomings and issues with hosting in IIS .....

Answer (score 3):

After some clicking around the project i've found the solution. If you right click on the Service Library project, under WCF Options, there is an option "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the solution" just uncheck that and it will stop.

Also, check Scott Chamberlain's answer, that might be the cause in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

If `WcfSvcHost` is starting then your hosting app is not starting. Even though you say you are starting the hosting app double check if you have the service library is set as a start-up project.

[image]

In the above image, Startup Project should be `HostingApp` you likely have it set to `WcfServiceLibrary`

---

One other possibility is your Hosting app is set up wrong, in the project settings for the hosting app, check that the output type is `Windows Application`.

[image]

If you had it set to `Class Library` then in your "Command line arguments" you have `/client:"WcfTestClient.exe"` that would also cause your issue. This can easily happen if you started the project as a "Serivice Library" but then later decided to turn it in to the hosting app.

Comment: I checked all of these and  i'm pretty sure i have all of the settings correct. I'm 100% sure my hosting app is starting (it's WPF and a window opens up where you can start / stop the service. but i also had this problem when i was using just a console app). I'm using VS 2013 Ultimate. I have some project dependencies, the hosting project is dependent on the service library which is dependant on another project. I have a single startup project set (the hosting app) which is a windows application, the service library is a Class Library.

Comment: I've got it! If you right click on the Service Library project, under WCF Options, there is an option "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the solution" just uncheck that.